# Need to programmatically initialise class variable array, how best do I do it?

Tags: c++, arrays, static, initialization, constants

In C++ I have an array of doubles which need initialising programmatically, at run time, just once, for the whole class to share. They could be both static and constant. How best can I initialise them? I have gone off using static with the prodigious popularity of parrallel processors presently pervading. So must I set a flag to run once or is there some static const magic which will initialise them as a variable local to a function (ok) or class (ok too)?

```
    double sumOfWeights = 0.0;
    double fracObs = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMTRACES; i++) {
        double weightAtI = SQUARED(1 - SQUARED(MAXTRACEWRTMIDTRACE * (MIDTRACE - i)
                                        / double(MIDTRACE)));
        sumOfWeights += weightAtI;
        fracObs += obsArray[i] * weightAtI;
    }
    return fracObs / sumOfWeights;
```

In the code above I'd like to make weightAtI a lookup with each double already divided by sumOfWeights so I can retrieve them without iterating through NUMTRACES.

_***EDIT*_**
It's okay, that's what constructors are for :)
Just hoping to tackle my static, const and initialization gremlins into the bargain. Thanks Seth

_***EDIT*_**
Not sure it is quite the effect I wanted though. The constructor runs on each instance, even if the members are static, no? No. Lemme see...

_***EDIT*_**
I think the most efficient solution, is to guard the initializer loop with a static flag, in the constructor. Being a POD flag I'm sure it should behave appropriately, I'm just not quite sure what that is at this stage.

_***EDIT*_**
Ahh, got it:

```
class X
{
public:
    static int i;
};
int X::i = 0; // definition outside class declaration
```

_***EDIT*_**
Unfortunately, when it comes to my code,

```
    static const int MIDTRACE = 3;
    static const int NUMTRACES = 2 * MIDTRACE + 1;
    static double WEIGHTATI[NUMTRACES];
```

I get linker errors:

> meobj.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A00001C) "private: static double * mens:meclass::PIMPL::WEIGHTATI" (?WEIGHTATI@PIMPL@meclass@mens@@$$Q0PANA)
>   meobj.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static double * mens:meclass::PIMPL::WEIGHTATI" (?WEIGHTATI@PIMPL@meclass@mens@@$$Q0PANA)

due to my constructor:

```
meclass::PIMPL() {
    if (!doneStaticInit) {
        double sumOfWeights = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMTRACES; i++) {
            WEIGHTATI[i] = SQUARED(1 - SQUARED(MAXTRACEWRTMIDTRACE * (MIDTRACE - i) / double(MIDTRACE)));
            sumOfWeights += WEIGHTATI[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMTRACES; i++) WEIGHTATI[i] /= sumOfWeights;
        doneStaticInit = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be explicitly and not programmatically initialized.

Comment: +1 for the prodigious popularity of parrallel processors presently pervading.

Comment: Prodigious populatrity of parrallel processors presently pervading?! Please tell me you wrote that intentionally!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `static bool` flag in your constructor. The flag will only be initialized to `false` the first time it is called. After that it will remain true.

```
// foo.h

class Foo {
  static const int MIDTRACE = 3; // static const, no definition needed
  static const int NUMTRACES = 2 * MIDTRACE + 1; // static const, no definition needed
  static double WEIGHTATI[NUMTRACES]; // not const, so need definition outside of class
public:
  Foo() {
    static bool array_initialized = false;
    if( !array_initialized ) {
      // Initialize array
      array_initialized = true;
    }
  }
  // Other members
};
```

In a source file, not header file:

```
// foo.cpp
include "foo.h"
double Foo::WEIGHTATI[NUMTRACES];
```

Comment: How would I go about initializing the static array of doubles? I'm getting errors (shown in updated OP). Everything seems to require explicit initialization and hinder programmatic initialization.

Comment: You still need to define your `static double WEIGHTATI[NUMTRACES]` in a source file, outside of your class: `double meclass::WEIGHTATI[NUMTRACES];`. And your constructor should have the same name as the class: `meclass::meclass()`.

Comment: PIMPL is a the subclass, meclass is a mere wrapper. <code>double meclass::WEIGHTATI[NUMTRACES];</code> is a declaration not definition.? As this is all in the body I chucked them up the top as non member variables.

Comment: Any non-const static member variable should be declared in the class, and defined once outside of the class. And a subclass can't access a private variable in a superclass, so you need to make it protected.

Comment: the second comment here works and makes more elegant code. Thanks JohnPS

Answer (score 2):

Initialization => constructor. Once => static instance. So one way is static instance of something with constructor.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Initializing them values..." << std::endl;
        for( int i = 0;  i < 3;  ++i )
        {
            values[i] = i;
        }
    };

    int values[3];
};

void doThings()
{
    static Foo const    foo;        // Is initialized ONCE.

    for( int i = 0;  i < 3;  ++i )
    {
        std::cout << foo.values[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    doThings();
    doThings();
    doThings();
}
```

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: That's pretty much what I'd edited to include, if site didn't reject it, ____EDIT____
It's okay, that's what constructors are for :)
Just hoping to tackle my static, const and initialization gremlins into the bargain.

Comment: The thing about doing it in the constructor is that it will be re-initialised upon each instantiation. Furthermore you haven't declared your/my array as static, hence or otherwise your explanation "Once => static instance" is, IMHO, left wanting. Sorry if you thought I wanted a class for static use, I must make that clearer.

Comment: @John: I changed the code to make it more clear. In both the original and current code, `foo` is static, const and initialized once. But if you run this new code you can *see* that it's only initialized once.

Comment: @John: your 1st sentence is wrong. your 2nd sentence is wrong. your 3rd sentence, i don't understand it, i think it's meaningless.

Comment: The cpp file this is in has just been PIMPL'd and already contains at least 4 private inner classes or structs. Any way I can just make a POD array of double initialize the once in the containing object's constructor?

Comment: Of course your constructor is only called once. Even I know a static local persists between calls.

Comment: @John: re "Any way I can just make a POD array of double initialize the once in the containing object's constructor?", that's what the above code does.

Comment: Yes, I suppose just getting a bit deep into encapsulation for just a static array, I'd rather the expense of it reinitialising each time the non-static constructor is called for those non-static objects. Or guard the initialization with a static flag. Is it (only) Java that has a static constructor? PS I want to see static members in action (or creation).